# Use of static in a function

Tags: c, static

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct node* node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data=data;
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right=NULL;

    return (node);
};

int height(struct node* root)
{
    static int lheight,rheight;
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
        lheight=height(root->left)+1;
        rheight=height(root->right)+1;
        if(lheight>rheight)
            return lheight;
        else
            return rheight;
    }

}

int main()
    {
          struct node* root=newNode(1);
          root->left=newNode(2);
          root->right       = newNode(3);
          root->left->left  = newNode(4);
          root->left->right = newNode(5);
          printf("%d",height(root));
          return 0;
    }
```

This program gives two different result. One is 2 for the above program where I use static and 3 if static is not used. Please explain the reason for the change in output using static.

Comment: Please, search before asking questions.

Comment: I cannot understand the difference for this particular problem.

Comment: No, it's not that. You want someone to do your homework which we don't do. Please read the link.

Comment: I have gone through the link . I completely understand what it means. But why two different output for this particular code is what i cannot understand.

Comment: I sounds you are doing homework/interviewing for a job .. neither should be answered

Comment: I just want to know the difference so that I can learn.

Comment: This code should not even compile! How did you get what it *returns*?

Comment: For me it is compiling.

Comment: Note the the part of the answer in the duplicate question: "Static in a function means the variable keeps its value between invocations". That is the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a local variable `static`, there's only one copy of that variable, not a separate copy for each call to the function. So when you call `height()` recursively, it overwrites the variables that are in use in the calling function.

Here's what's happening. First the function does:

```
lheight = height(root->left)+1;
```

This sets `lheight` to the height of the left branch of the current node + 1. Then you call:

```
rheight = height(root->right)+1;
```

Inside the recursive call to `height`, it again does:

```
lheight = height(root->left)+1;
```

So now `lheight` no longer contains the height of the parent's left branch, it contains the height of the right child's left branch + 1.

If you don't use `static`, each recursive level has its own variables, they aren't overwritten when you make the recursive calls.

Comment: I understand that. But why here two different outputs?

Comment: Step through the function, either with a debugger or by writing the variables on a piece of paper, and see what happens.

Comment: But there are two different static variables one is lheight and the other is rheight.

Comment: But you're updating both variables during each recursive call. So after you set `lheight`, you then call `height` again on the right branch, and it overwrites `lheight`.